# Flask .env variables get read when running in pipenv shell, but not .venv

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, gunicorn, secret-key

I have a React-Flask application that works well locally, but I've run into issues upon attempting to deploy it to Render. The home page loads, but when one attempts to log in, the server returns a 500 every time.

When I ran the app using gunicorn on my local system, I thought things were going smoothly. But I've come to realize the discrepancy, I think: My `config.py` file loads the `secret_key` from my `.env` file, using `load_dotenv()`. It works fine when I run gunicorn *while within pipenv shell.* But if I run guinicorn just in the default .venv, attempting to log in bounces back an error saying that "no secret key was set." Using good old-fashioned print statements, I can confirm this: the `secret_key` is read just fine by my config when running from within pipenv shell, but when running in .venv, it's just blank.

So, my working theory is that Render's Start Command (which executes gunicorn) would not be able to get into the pipenv shell, and that's why the deployed version is not working. But I have no idea how to fix that. Maybe something can be patched up with the `requirements.txt`? I'm not sure. I think this is exposing my lack of fluency with understanding different virtual environments, so I've got my work cut out for me there. In the meantime, though, does anyone have a light they may be able to shine here on what may be happening or how to fix it?

I attempted to add the command to enter pipenv shell to the start command on Render, but that doesn't work. I also tried various other commands from dotenv (find, etc) to see if that helped .venv to find the variable appropriately, but no luck. I've also tried accessing the variable through bracket notation instead of .get, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Use of `.env` files is a feature of `pipenv shell`, not of Python. If you want your script to use value in a `.env` file regardless of the environment in which it is run, you need to use a library like `dotenv`.

Comment: I am indeed using `dotenv`--my config file imports `dotenv` and `os`, and runs `load_dotenv()`, before setting `app.secret_key` to be equal to `os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')`. This works well when I run my application from within the `pipenv shell`. But my deployment on Render does not seem to be getting the secret key imported properly.

Comment: It sounds like `load_dotenv` simply can't find your `.env` file, so silently does nothing (rather than raising an exception). I would try `assert os.path.exists("/where/you/think/.env/is")` to confirm.

Comment: It was finding the file, because other variables in the `.env` file were coming through. I think I've found the solution: The `SECRET_KEY` was a byte string, and it wasn't getting decoded properly somehow in the .venv, but it WAS getting decoded properly in the pipenv shell. Why that is, I don't know, further research is needed on my part. For now I've changed the `SECRET_KEY` to be a plain string, and everything's working fine. Thanks for the replies!